# Decomposing a polynomial ring as a graded ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let's say I have a ring $A$. Then if we want to decompose $A[x]$ as a graded ring, then correct me if I'm wrong, but the construction goes as follows - we have an isomorphism
$$A[x] \cong \bigoplus_{d \geq 0}A_d$$
where $A_0 = A$ (technically this is identifying the image of the injection $A \hookrightarrow A[X]$ with $A$) and $A_d = \left(x^d\right)$.

But if this were the case then there would be elements of the direct sum which I could express non-uniquely. For example take $x^2 \in A[x]$. Then I could express $x^2$ as either
$$x^2 = 0 + x\cdot x + 0 + \dots \in \bigoplus_{d \geq 0}A_d$$
or as $$x^2 = 0 + 0 + 1\cdot x^2 + \dots \in \bigoplus_{d \geq 0}A_d$$
which contradicts the fact that elements of a direct sum of rings are always expressed uniquely. Which part of my understanding is incorrect and what is the correct way to decompose $A[x]$ as a graded ring?

Comment: $A_d$ is not the ideal $(x^d)$; it's the $A$-module $A x^d = \{a x^d : a \in A\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A_d$ is an $A_0$-module, not an $A[x]$-module. Hence $x\cdot x$ can't be an element of $A_1$.